# Process for Public/Private key pair to sign arbitrary data

Tags: .net, cryptography, bouncycastle

I've got a system which holds very sensitive data. There are stiff restrictions on what can be exported.

Currently, someone with an admin role needs to log in to do the export. We need to change this so that someone can create an "export authorisation" file which, when fed into the system, will allow the export.

I'm thinking of a which is something like....

```
{"User":"Bob","Definition":{/*Some Criteria*/}}
[Signature for the Json using admin's key]
```

The server would have the Admin's public key and would use it and the signature to confirm the Json is unmodified. **NB:** I'd prefer that the Json be plain-text rather than encrypted as it makes the requests easier to audit at a glance.

That's great in theory but I'm having some issues with the implementation. From the look of it, [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/) is the crypto library I need (This has to work on both .Net and Java components so learning a single library seems like a good idea).

Where I'm struggling is picking the correct algorithm and working out how to use it correctly with BC. It seems to provide a lot of building blocks but not much information on how to put them together.

So... What are the steps/components required to sign an arbitrary string and verify that signature?

Comment: Come on spelling error that was caught by SO.  Sorry you are brit.  SO is smart.

Comment: @Blam Sorry, can you try that again but using full sentences? I don't quite follow... Edit: Ah, Authori_s_ation?

Comment: As you have noticed (+1 for that; most people don't), building a secure protocol or application out of cryptographic primitives is a very difficult task. In fact it is so difficult that even experts don't always get it right. The worst part is that you don't know if it's right or not until it's too late.

Comment: @ntoskrnl You're definitely right about the "worst part". I've now managed to get something running which takes text, signs it and verifies the signature - but I have absolutely no idea if it's secure. I sense it might be time to hire a contractor...